# oracle apex public user admin privilege to perform some specific action

Tags: oracle-apex

It is the requirement that a specific user of oracle apex application can be able to reset password of other users when necessary.
I have written this code for the desired function on button "Change Password" Click event.

```
BEGIN
 APEX_UTIL.REMOVE_USER(p_user_name => :P16_USER_ID);
 APEX_UTIL.CREATE_USER(
        p_user_name=> :P16_USER_ID,
        p_web_password=> :P16_USER_ID
      );
 end;
```

But it gives the following message.

> User requires ADMIN privilege to perform this operation. Contact your
>   application administrator.

Answer (score 2):

Something tells me this is a bad idea. But if you must, the user that is allowed to do this must be an administrator, which can be set in the Administration section.

Second, I'd use `APEX_UTIL.EDIT_USER`, rather than a delete-and-create.

Comment: If I use APEX_UTIL.EDIT_USER as you mentioned , It still gives error that admin privilege.

Answer (score 2):

Never ever give extra privileges to APEX_PUBLIC_USER, this will open security breaches since APEX_PUBLIC_USER is used for every database connexions.

If you are calling this stored procedure or package in an APEX application, the Schema owner should get the privilege to do so.

Comment: But It is the requirement that A  specific public user can change the passwords of other users.Then how to solve it?